# Do vacuum virtual patricles have mass?

Tags: mass, charge, virtual-particles

When a particle and antiparticle pair is produced their charge sum is zero,momentum sum is zero but the mass sum isn't.Does that mean that possibly for the mass there is no need of starting equilibrium and so the virtual particles have mass at their own?I am not stating there should be negative mass but only curious how mass can pop up out without any conservation law.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell

Comment: Useful background reading, imo: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/

Comment: It is not meaningful to talk about the mass of virtual particles because they aren’t “on the mass shell” and (thus) they aren’t “particles” at all.

Comment: I still have difficulties to understand intrinsic particle feature that in interaction with HB produces the effect of mass.Sorry for that....maybe there are doors that cannot be opened.